# "not equal value or type to", isnt working properly: Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
function myFunction() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000-1+1))+1;

    
    if ((String(randomNumber).substring(-1) !== "7") || (String(randomNumber).substring(-1) !== "8") || (String(randomNumber).substring(-1) !== "9")) {
        alert(randomNumber);
    }
    else{
        myFunction();
        return;
    }
}
```

The output should be so that 7, 8 and 9 can't be the last digit, and if it is it will be skipped.
But it doesn't seem to work, 7, 8 and 9 is frequently the last digit in the integer. Can somebody help me to get this working?

EDIT:
`(String(randomNumber).substring(String(randomNumber).length-1) !== "7")`
DOES THE TRICK

Comment: `x === "0" || "8" || "9"` will always compare `x` to `"0"`.

Comment: But i use !== so that it isn't allowed to be 0, 8 or 9. How come it happens frequently?

Comment: I would recommend you read about operator predcedence https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence (it will help, but it may not completely answer your question)

Comment: So what im reading is that you "cant" use 3 or gates in sequence of each other because if 'a' is false 'b' is true and so forth?

Comment: The question has now changed, and my answer is no longer valid. I don't think this question is helpful anymore.

Comment: This question could be more useful to the community if you ask about a more specific problem in your code. Examples of more specific questions are *How can I check equality against multiple values?* or *How can I get the last character in a string?*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TLDR

```js
x !== ("0" || "8" || "9")
```

If the comparison is meant to be "x is not '0' or '8' or '9', then it will need to be split into different comparisons.

```js
x !== "0" || x !== "8" || x !== "9"
```

---

### What's happening in the original comparison?

The parens `()` are grouping `"0" || "8" || "9"` which is resulting in `"0"`.

This group is being compared first, before `===`, due to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

How come the result of the group is `"0"`?

The [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) checks if the left-hand argument is "truthy". If yes, then it is returned, if no, the right-hand argument is returned.

For example:

```js
let variable = A || B
```

If `A` is truthy, `A` is assigned to `variable`, otherwise `B` is assigned to `variable`.

---

Apologies if the wrong terminology is used.

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful. I will split the comparison and see if it works then! :))

Comment: If it doesn’t work, please update the question with a [mcve].

Comment: No it didnt, im making a minimal reproducible example at the moment

Comment: @JonasLarsen the code has changed completely. This answer is not appropriate anymore.